# I cant figure out why this function returnes none all the time

Tags: python

**Thank you so so much every boby that answerd. I am really gratefull for your advise:)**
I made this function and it is supposed to return the converted value of a conversion between either Celsius/Fahrenheit or Kg/lbs:

```
def convert (nr1, nr2, ctype):
    if ctype == 1:
        if nr2 == " ":
            def kg_lbs (nr1):
                return nr1 * 2.2046
        if nr1 == " ":
            def lbs_kg (nr2):
                return nr2 / 2.2046
    if ctype == 2:
        if nr2 == " ":
            def cel_far (nr1):
                return nr1 * 1.80000000 + 32
        if nr1 == " ":
            def far_cel (nr2):
                return (nr2 - 32)/1.8000000
```

you give it the first number (Celsius or kg) and the the second number (Fahrenheit or lbs) (you indicate which way you want to covert with a space) and after giving number 1 and number 2 you give it the conversion type (i.e. converting between F/C or Kg/Lbs).

The issue is: no matter what values I provide, it only returns `None`.

(I'm new to python so if the error seems obvious that's why)
Can some one tell me what's wrong?

Comment: The reason your function returns `None` is because it doesn't have any `return` statements itself, despite containing four function declarations which have their own `return` statements. What are the `def far_cel(...):` lines for - why declare these as functions instead of just writing `return` statements?

Comment: You shouldnt be defining fuctions in an if statement. Has to recreate them everytime the parent function is called. Also these functions never get returned or called.

Comment: Why are you defining functions within the function? You don't use them, and don't return them.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, you should not be defining functions within your function. Those secondary functions do return values, though your original `convert()` function has no returns. If you remove all of the second function definitions and properly indent, then your function should work as expected.

```
def convert(nr1, nr2, ctype):
  '''This function converts inputed units to another measurement system
  lbs to kg or Celsius to Fahrenheit depending on a passed through integer
  for conversion type'''
  if ctype == 1:
    if nr2 == " ":
        return nr1 * 2.2046
    if nr1 == " ":
        return nr2 / 2.2046

  if ctype == 2:
    if nr2 == " ":
        return nr1 * 1.80000000 + 32
    if nr1 == " ":
        return (nr2 - 32)/1.8000000

print(convert(1, ' ', 1))
```

this returns 2.2046 as expected. I don't want to go in too far with your syntax as you're still learning but this is a good start. Try to see how you can incorporate elif/else statements instead of back to back ifs

Comment: What does "much like comments" imply? Are you suggesting that documenting your code is a bad idea?

Comment: @Mad Physicist The comments on the original question.

Comment: I made a small edit. Hope you don't mind. My mind went totally elsewhere with the original wording.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong here. First of all, your main function (`convert`), doesn't return anything. Instead it defines functions, which in turn return  something. Keep in mind that when you do:

```
def convert (nr1, nr2, ctype):
if ctype == 1:
    if nr2 == " ":
        def kg_lbs (nr1):
            return nr1 * 2.2046
```

Then your `convert` function doesn't return anything. Instead, the `return` statement indicates the return value of the `kg_lbs` function that is being defined inside the `convert` function.

The second thing that's wrong (or at the very least, not optimal), is: why are you defining functions inside functions in the first place? This means that every time `convert` is called, a new function is being created, not very efficient! You could implement your conversion functions outside `convert`, and call them from `convert`. The following code should do what you need:

```
def kg_lbs (nr1):
   return nr1 * 2.2046

def lbs_kg (nr2):
   return nr2 / 2.2046

def cel_far (nr1):
   return nr1 * 1.80000000 + 32

def far_cel (nr2):
   return (nr2 - 32)/1.8000000

def convert (nr1, nr2, ctype):
    if ctype == 1:
        if nr2 == " ":
            return kg_lbs (nr1)
        if nr1 == " ":
            return lbs_kg (nr2)
    if ctype == 2:
        if nr2 == " ":
            return cel_far (nr1)
        if nr1 == " ":
            return far_cel (nr2)
```

You can try it out:

```
convert(5," ",1) # returns 11.023
```